# multiplying complex numbers in C

Tags: c, algorithm, math, complex-numbers

My code seems working but the online judge doesn't accept it. Here's the instruction:

> Problem Statement
> Write a C Program that will compute for the product of two complex numbers.
>
> Input
>
> Input starts with a number N
> and is followed by N
> pairs of complex numbers of the form a + bi, c + di

> Output
>
> The product of the two complex numbers.

> Limits
>
> 1<=N<=20
>
> The parts of the complex numbers are integers.

> Notes
>
> Problems will have test cases that are not listed in their specification. Your solution must produce the right output for these hidden test cases.

> Sample Input #1

```
3
1 + 2i, 3 - 4i
3 - 2i, 2 + 3i
9 - 2i, 3 - 2i
```

> Sample Output #1

```
11 + 2i
12 + 5i
23 - 24i
```

Here's my code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int a, b, c, d;
        char sign1, sign2;
      
        scanf("%d %c %di, %d %c %di", &a, &sign1, &b, &c, &sign2, &d);

        if (sign1 == '-')
            b = -b;
        if (sign2 == '-')
            d = -d;

        int real = (a * c) - (b * d);
        int im = (b * c) + (a * d);

        if (im < 0) {
          if(real != 0){
            printf("%d %c %di\n", real, '-', -im); }
          else {
            printf("%c %di\n", '-', -im);
        } }

        else if (im > 0){
          if(real != 0){
            printf("%d %c %di\n", real, '+', im); }
          else {
            printf("%di\n", im);
          }}

        else if (im == 0){
          if(real != 0){
            printf("%d\n", real);
          }
          else{
            printf("0\n");
          }
        }
      }
    
  
    return 0;
}
```

ps. sorry my code's messy. i have just started learning

Comment: Is your output in fact the *exact* same as the sample output? Down to the spacing? You didn't provide the output of your code.

Comment: Aside: you should always check the return value from `scanf()`. Maybe not related to your problem, but definitely required if you want a robust program.

Comment: You're trying hard to output the human output: `0 + 5i` --> `5i` and `7 + 0i` --> `7`. Maybe you should output the full versions instead of the shortened ones. You don't handle the short versions on input. So, what does the problem statement say about this?

Comment: You should check the return value from the `scanf()` call to ensure you got 6 values.  That said, for an online challenge like this, the input is always valid so you'll get away with not checking, but checking would reassure you that the input is OK.  Have you printed the inputs you do get?  That's a basic form of checking — even if it's not what will be used in the final submitted version of your program.

Comment: For the sample input, your code seems to produce the correct output.  The sample data doesn't have results with either the real or imaginary part being zero; that could cause you problems.  Are you supposed to drop 0 components as you do, or should you print `0 + 0i` etc?

Answer (score 1):

Suggested changes:

- Use wider math to prevent overflow.

```
    // int real = (a * c) - (b * d);
    long long real = (1LL* a * c) - (1LL* b * d);
```

Same for `im` and adjust print specifiers.

- Asymmetric output

Below 2 are not symmetric.  Perhaps negative imaginary values, when alone are printed without a subtraction sign.

```
    printf("%c %di\n", '-', -im);
    ... 
    printf("%di\n", im);
```

Suggest:

```
    printf("%di\n", im);
    ... 
    printf("%di\n", im);
```

... or maybe with a zero real part as in `0 - 2i`, `0 + 2i`.

or simply:

```
        long long real = (1LL * a * c) - (1LL * b * d);
        long long im = (1LL * b * c) + (1LL * a * d);
        printf("%lld %c %lldi\n", real, (im < 0 ? '-' : '+'), llabs(im));
```

- Check return value of `scanf()`.

Comment: What about the result of `(1 + 6i), (2 + 5i)` — which has a negative real component?  The specification shown so far doesn't cover such possibilities.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, guess I'll use the adage: "There are 2 kinds of people in this world: those who can draw conclusions from incomplete information."